# Если я использую RewriteRule, то редирект идет по коду 301? Или по другому?

Tags: php, .htaccess

Сейчас я использую полный редирект 302 таким образом:

```
Redirect 302 / http://new.site.com/folder/
```

Код 302 использован специально.

Вот нашел код по своему запросу редиректить отовсюду кроме определенной папки.

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/somefolder 
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://new.site.com/ [L,R]
```

Но как заставить работать его по коду 302?

Comment: Если верить [документации](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r), то RewriteRule по умолчанию создает как раз редирект с кодом 302.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь все просто, вам просто нужно установить 302 переадресацию.

**RewriteRule** - правило подстановки. Если запрос подходит под вышестоящие проверки и [ШАБЛОН], то применяется правило подстановки. Здесь регулировать поведение также можно с помощью флагов. Флаги есть разные, пример необходимых:

**R=302**   - Будет редирект с кодом 302, можно указать другой код
**L** - Это последнее правило, больше не применять правил преобразований

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/somefolder 
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://new.site.com/ [R=302,L]
```